# Interpretation of method plt.fill_between()? Discussion

Tags: matplotlib, plot, svm

A question for discussion:

The matplotlib documentation says that the method `plt.fill_between` is used to "fill the area between two horizontal curves".

**What exactly is meant by "horizontal"?** Intuitively, I would say "two parallel curves". Like in [this example](https://github.com/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/05.07-Support-Vector-Machines.ipynb)

[image]

The curves are not horizontal, but parallel.

Comment: no one but you see that link

Comment: The link you provided is to a ipython notebook in your filesystem, not a link to web hosted code

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to post this link: https://github.com/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/05.07-Support-Vector-Machines.ipynb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Two horizontal curves" is a set of data where you have two arrays `y1` and `y2` defined on a single support `x`.
Equally, "two vertical curves" would be a set of data where you have a single `y` support for two `x` arrays.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: That makes it clear, what "horizontal curves" means in terms of matplotlib!